# Inconsistent ReferenceError in javascript using firefox's scratchpad

Tags: javascript, firefox

I'm experimenting with javascript to learn a bit about the language, and I came across a weird behaviour.

Consider this example:

```
function hello(name) {
  let greet = 'Hello '
  alert(greet + name)
}

hello('world')
alert(greet)
```

This, of course, shows "Hello world" first, and throws `ReferenceError: greet is not defined` afterwards.

Next example:

```
function hello(name) {
  var greet = 'Hello '
  alert(greet + name)
}

hello('world')
alert(greet)
```

Again, `ReferenceError`, as I expected.

Last example:

```
function hello(name) {
  greet = 'Hello '
  alert(greet + name)
}

hello('world')
alert(greet)
```

Shows "Hello world" followed by "Hello ", expected.

If I now change the code back to my first or second example I keep getting the results from the last example. It never throws the `ReferenceError` again.

Is this a quirk/bug in firefox's scratchpad? or is there something I'm missing about the language?

Answer (score 1):

The scratchpad, like the console, runs in the context of the currently loaded webpage.

Clicking "Run" does not run the script in a clean environment, it runs it in the existing page.

If you create a global, then that global persists in the page until the reload it.

Comment: You are correct. As soon as I move to a different tab the error is back. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is not a bug and is the expected behavior. When you do not have a variable declaration, the variable is created in **global** scope. Hence you did not get the error.

```
function hello(name) {
  greet = 'Hello '
  alert(greet + name)
}

hello('world')
alert(greet)
```

The variable `greet` is created in **global** scope.

From MDN:

> Assigning a value to an undeclared variable implicitly creates it as a
>   global variable (it becomes a property of the global object) when the
>   assignment is executed.

Comment: Ok, but if I add back the declaration, I still don't get the error

Comment: Run the command `delete greet`? Repeat your code with declaration and you can again get the error as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Press `CTRL+F5` to refresh the page and the error will return.

When you define `greet` it is holding the value and is why it will not throw the error anymore.